# How to call multiple API route in getStaticPaths nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have created single page, but can not pass value multiple API routes in getStaticPaths, I have called 3 API but If i use single working fine for example. But called mutiple API not working.

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const topMenu = await fetch('https://lencashapp.ae/api/v5/web/home',{
          method:'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({ title: "React POST Request Example" }),
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    
        })
        const menus = await topMenu.json();
        const trending_path=menus.sections.trending;
const paths = trending_path.map((post) => ({
      params:
       { 
        list: `${post.store_label}`,///////////////////////////
        id: `${post.store_id}`,
    }
  })) 
    return { paths, fallback:false, }
}
```

but I found length then passed not working could you please solve this issue. Goto my getStaticPaths function.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Link from 'next/link'
import "reactjs-popup/dist/index.css";
import Layout from '../../../components/layout';


    
class Store extends Component {
  // const router = useRouter()
  // const { Id } = router.query
  // console.log(this.state.data) 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: props.storeDetails, 
      dataComments:props.comment,
      dataRelated:props.related,
      visible: 6,
      isLoading: true,
      dataLoaded: false,
    };
    this.loadMore = this.loadMore.bind(this);
  } 
  loadMore() {
    this.setState({
        visible: this.state.visible + 2,
        dataLoaded: this.state.visible >= this.state.dataRelated.length
    });
  }
   render(){
     
    if (!this.state.data) {
      return null;
    }
    if (!this.state.dataComments) {
      return null;
    }
    var k;
  var categoryName=this.state.data.category_name; 
  var categoryDec=this.state.data.description;
  console.log(categoryDec) 
       
var i,k;

// offerList Section
const membership_offers = this.state.data.offer_list.membership;
    const lencashay_offers = this.state.data.offer_list.lencashay;
    const voucher_offers = this.state.data.offer_list.lencash_voucher;
    console.log(this.state.data);
    const membership_terms = this.state.data.store_terms.membership;
    const lencashay_terms = this.state.data.store_terms.lencashay;
    const voucher_terms = this.state.data.store_terms.lencash_voucher;

    const membership_howto = this.state.data.how_to.membership;
    const lencashay_howto = this.state.data.how_to.lencashay;
    const voucher_howto = this.state.data.how_to.lencash_voucher;

  return(
    <> 
    <div>
    <Layout>
      
    <Head>
    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
    <title>lencash - Cash Rewards, Voucher, Payments, Deals</title> 
            <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
            <meta name="google-site-verification" content="rtIRrUNRpgZ_lFtlfS8LJ0-8j_d569BXS9NOGa_nM6Y" /> 
          </Head>  
        <div>
        <Grid className="breadcrumb-section">
            <Grid.Column width={16}>
            <div class="ui breadcrumb">
               <Link  href="http://localhost:3000" className="section">
                 <a>Home</a>
                 </Link>
               <i class="right angle icon divider"></i>          
               <Link  href="#" className="active section"><a>{this.state.data.category_name}</a></Link>
               <i class="right angle icon divider"></i>
               <Link  href="http://localhost:3000" className="active section"><a>{this.state.data.store_name}</a></Link>
            </div>
              </Grid.Column>
         </Grid>     
          
          <Grid className="storedetails">
            <Grid.Column width={11}>
              <div className="storeImage">
                <div className="store-bg">
                  <h1>
                    {this.state.data.store_name}
                    
                  </h1>
                  
                  <h2>
                  <span className="store-right">
                      {
                        (i =
                          0 < this.state.data.rating ? (
                            <p>
                              <span className="rateNumber">
                                {this.state.data.rating}
                              </span>
                              <Icon  className="star"></Icon>
                            </p>
                          ) : ( 
                            // <p className="no-reviews">No Reviews</p>
                            <></>
                          ))
                      }
                    </span>
                    </h2>
                  <p className="store-category"><span>{this.state.data.category_name}</span> </p>
                  <p className="">{this.state.data.summary} </p>
                  {/* <p><span className='rateNumber'>{this.state.data.rating}</span><Icon className='star'/><Icon className='star'/><Icon className='star'/><Icon className='star'/><Icon className='star'/><span className='totalRate'>39000</span></p> */}
                  {/* <div
                    className="store-back"
                    Style={
                      "background: url(" + this.state.data.store_images + ")"
                    }
                  > */}
                  <div> 
                    {/* <img src= alt="" className='storeImage'/> */}
                    <img
                      src={this.state.data.store_images}
                      alt={this.state.data.store_name +" - UAE"}
                      className="store-back"
                      Style="width: 100%!important"
                    />
                    <img
                      src={this.state.data.logo}
                      alt=""
                      className="storeImageLogo"
                     style={{width: '60px',right: '0', position: 'absolute', bottom: '0', marginRight: '10px',
                     marginBottom: '10px!important'}}/>
                     <img
                      src="/images/logo512.png"
                      alt=""
                      className="store-lencash-logo"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="related-section">
                {membership_offers.length !== 0 && (
          <div className="offer">
            <h3 className="how-work">
              <span>Memberships</span>
              <span>
                <Link  href="#"><a>How this works?</a></Link>
              </span>
            </h3>
            <Slider   {...settings}>
             
              {membership_offers.map((x, i) => (
                <div className="item" key={i}>
                  <div className="border">
                    <div className="item-1">
                      <p>
                        <span>
                          <img src="/images/store-details/aed.jpg" alt="" />
                        </span>
                        <span className="aedText">AED</span>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                    <p>{x.cashback}</p>
                    <p>{x.label}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
            </Slider>

            <div className="offer-terms">
              <h3>Membership Terms</h3>
              <h4>General Terms</h4>
              {membership_terms["general_terms"] && (
                <ul className="general-terms">
                  {" "}
                  {membership_terms["general_terms"].map((x, i) => (
                    <li>{x}</li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              )}

              {membership_terms["store_terms"] !== 0 && (
                <div>
                  {membership_terms["store_terms"] && (
                    <ul className="store-terms">
                      {" "}
                      {membership_terms["store_terms"].map((x, i) => (
                        <li>{x}</li>
                      ))}
                    </ul>
                  )}
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
        {lencashay_offers.length !== 0 && (
          <div className="offer">
            <h3 className="how-work">
              <span>lencashay</span>
              <span>
                <Link  href="#"><a>How this works?</a></Link>
              </span>
            </h3>
            
              <Slider  className="offer-list-section"    {...settings}>
              {lencashay_offers.map((x, i) => (
                
                      <div className="item " key={i}>
                        <div>
                        <Popup
                  trigger={
                    <div>
                        <div className="border">
                          <div className="item-1">
                            <p className="lencashLabel">{x.label.slice(0, 8)}</p>
                            <p className="lencash-label-2">
                              {x.label.slice(8, 32)}
                            </p>
                          </div>
                           <p className="lencashTime">{x.time_label}</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                       }
                       modal
                       nested
                     >
                        {(close) => (
                    <div className="modal">
                      <button className="close" onClick={close}>
                        &times;
                      </button>
                      <div className="header">                       
                      </div>
                      <div className="content">
                      <div>
                        <p> 
                          Currently, payment & voucher transactions can be done
                          from lencash mobile app.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          Search for "lencash" on Play Store or App Store to
                          download the app & earn cash rewards.
                        </p>
                        <p> Or scan QR code below.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        <img
                          src="/images/lencash-onelink.png"
                          className="popup-top-img"
                        />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  )}
                </Popup>
                    </div>
                 
                 
                </div>
              ))}
            </Slider>

            <div className="offer-terms">
              <h3>lencashay Terms</h3>
              <h4>General Terms</h4>
              {lencashay_terms["general_terms"] && (
                <ul className="general-terms">
                  {" "}
                  {lencashay_terms["general_terms"].map((x, i) => (
                    <li>{x}</li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              )}
              {lencashay_terms["store_terms"] !== undefined && (
                <div>
                  <h4>Store Terms</h4>
                  {lencashay_terms["store_terms"] && (
                    <ul className="store-terms">
                      {" "}
                      {lencashay_terms["store_terms"].map((x, i) => (
                        <li>{x}</li>
                      ))}
                    </ul>
                  )}
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
        {voucher_offers.length !== 0 && (
          <div className="offer">
            <h3 className="how-work">
              <span>Vouchers</span>
              <span>
                <Link  href="#"><a>How this works?</a></Link>
              </span>
            </h3>
            <Slider  className="offer-list-section"    {...settings}>
              {voucher_offers.map((x, i) => (
                <Popup
                  trigger={
                    <div>
                      <div className="item" key={i}>
                        <div className="border">
                          <div className="item-1">
                            <p>
                              <span>
                                <img
                                  src="/images/store-details/aed.jpg"
                                  alt=""
                                />
                              </span>
                              <span className="aedText">AED</span>
                            </p>
                          </div>
                          <p>{x.voucher_amount}</p>
                          <p>{x.label}</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  }
                  modal
                  nested
                >
                  {(close) => (
                    <div className="modal">
                      <button className="close" onClick={close}>
                        &times;
                      </button>
                      <div className="header">
                       
                      </div>
                      <div className="content">
                        <div>
                        <p> 
                          Currently, payment & voucher transactions can be done
                          from lencash mobile app.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          Search for "lencash" on Play Store or App Store to
                          download the app & earn cash rewards.
                        </p>
                        <p> Or scan QR code below.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        <img
                          src="/images/lencash-onelink.png"
                          className="popup-top-img"
                        />
                        </div>
                        
                      </div>
                      
                    </div>
                  )}
                </Popup>
              ))}
            </Slider>
            <div className="offer-terms">
              <h3>Voucher Terms</h3>
              <h4>General Terms</h4>
              {voucher_terms["general_terms"] && (
                <ul className="general-terms">
                  {" "}
                  {voucher_terms["general_terms"].map((x, i) => (
                    <li>{x}</li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              )}
              <h4>Validity</h4>
              {voucher_terms["validity"] && (
                <ul className="validity">
                  {" "}
                  {voucher_terms["validity"].map((x, i) => (
                    <li>{x}</li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        )}

                  </div>
              </div>
            </Grid.Column>
            <Grid.Column className="four-1" width={5}>
              <div className="storeAbout" centered>
                <h3>About</h3>
                {/* <p>{categoryDec}</p> */}
                <p
                  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: categoryDec,
                  }}
                ></p>
              </div>
        
              <div>
        { 
        (this.state.dataComments.length > 0) ?
        <div className="customerReview" centered>
          <h3>Customer Review </h3>
          
        { 
        (this.state.dataComments.length > 0) ?
        <div>
          {this.state.dataComments.map((x, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
              <h3>
                <span className="cusomerHead">{x.user_name.split("")[0]}</span>
                <span>{x.user_name}</span>
              </h3>


              <p>{x.comment}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
          </div>
          :<div><p className='cus-review'><span>No Review</span></p></div>}
        </div>
        :<div></div>
        }
      </div>
      <div className="related-stores" centered>
          <h3 className="realted-heading">Related Stores </h3>
          {/* <p className="categories-title"><span>{this.props.catNameReview}</span></p> */}
        <Grid className="">
        {this.state.dataRelated.slice(0, this.state.visible).map((x, i) => {
            return (
              <Grid.Column columns={8} key={i}>
                <Segment>
                  <Card>
                    
                    <div className="image">
                    {/* <Link href={"../../store"+"/"+x.name+"/"+x.store_id } passHref={true}> */}
                     <a> <img src={x.image} wrapped ui={false} className="img related"/></a>
                      {/* </Link>*/}
                      </div> 
                    
                    <img src={x.logo} alt="" className="collection-logo" />
                    <Card.Content Style={{background:'#fff',marginTop: '-6px'}}>
                    {/* <Link href={"../../store"+"/"+x.store_label+"/"+x.store_id } passHref={true}> */}
                        <a><Card.Header>{x.name}</Card.Header></a>
                      {/* </Link> */}
                      <Card.Description>{x.store_summary}</Card.Description>
                    </Card.Content>
                    <Card.Content extra>
                      <p className="rewards" Style={{background:'#fff'}}>
                        <span>
                          <img src="/images/rewards.png" alt="" className="img"/>
                        </span>
                        Rewards upto <span>AED {x.cashback}</span>
                      </p>
                      <p className="location">
                        <span>
                          <img src="/images/location.png" alt="" className="img"/>
                        </span>
                        <span className="store-location" key="index">{x.store_branches}</span>
                        {/* {x.store_branches.map((locations, index) => (
                          <span className="store-location" key="index">
                            {index === 0 ? (
                              <span>{locations.store_location}</span>
                            ) : index >= 1 ? (
                              <span>
                                ,&nbsp;&nbsp;{locations.store_location}
                              </span>
                            ) : null}
                          </span>
                        ))} */}
                      </p>
                    </Card.Content>
                  </Card>
                </Segment>
              </Grid.Column>
            );
          })}
        </Grid>
        {
        !this.state.dataLoaded && (
  <Grid>
     <Grid.Column width={16}>
        <p className="related-load">
           <span
              onClick={this.loadMore}
              className="btn btn-primary load-more"
              Style={{cursor:'pointer'}}>
              Loading Store
           </span>
       </p>
     </Grid.Column>
   </Grid>
)
}
        </div>
 
            </Grid.Column>
            
          </Grid>
          <Grid className="related-footer">
            <Grid.Column width={16}> 
            
            </Grid.Column>
          </Grid>
        </div>  
        </Layout>
        </div>
    </>

  )
}
}
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    // change your API url to get ALL categories
    const topMenu = await fetch('https://lencashapp.ae/api/v5/web/home',{
      method:'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ title: "React POST Request Example" }),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  
    })
    const menus = await topMenu.json();
    const trending_path=menus.sections.trending;
    const trending_path_length=menus.sections.trending.length;
    console.log(trending_path_length)
    const topbanner=menus.sections.banners.top_banners;
    const topbannerresult=menus.sections.banners.top_banners.length;
    console.log(topbannerresult)
    const promo=menus.sections.banners.bottom_banners;
    const promo_length=menus.sections.banners.bottom_banners.length;
    console.log(promo_length)
    const postOffer = {
      category_id: "" 
    };
    
    const offers = await fetch('https://lencashapp.ae/api/v4/web/list',{
    method:'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(postOffer),
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },

  })
  const offersValue = await offers.json();
  const offersResult=offersValue.stores;
  const offerLength=offersResult.length;
  
    // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on posts, play with params variable you are returning
    const collection = await fetch('https://lencashapp.ae/api/v5/web/home',{
      method:'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ title: "React POST Request Example" }),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  
    })
    const collectionApi = await collection.json();
    const collect=collectionApi.sections.collections;
    if(collect.length > 0 ){
      var collectionData=[];
    var count = Object.keys(collect).length; 
    
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      //  console.log(i)
      collectionData.push(
        <>
        {collect[i].stores_list.map((x, i) => ({
         params:
         { 
          list: `${x.store_label}`,///////////////////////////
          id: `${x.store_id}`,
      }
    }))}
          </>
      ); 
  } 
}
  if(offerLength > 0){
    const paths = offersResult.map((post) => ({
      params:
      { 
        list: `${post.store_label}`,///////////////////////////
        id: `${post.store_id}`,
    }
  }))
    
    // We'll pre-render only these paths at build time.
    // { fallback: blocking } will server-render pages
    // on-demand if the path doesn't exist.
    return { paths, fallback:false, }
  }
    if(trending_path_length > 0){
    const paths = trending_path.map((post) => ({
      params:
       { 
        list: `${post.store_label}`,///////////////////////////
        id: `${post.store_id}`,
    }
  })) 
    return { paths, fallback:false, }
}
if(topbannerresult > 0){
  const paths = topbanner.map((post) => ({
    params:
     { 
      list: `${post.store_label}`,///////////////////////////
      id: `${post.link_to}`,
  }
})) 
  return { paths, fallback:false, }
}
if(promo_length > 0){
  const paths = promo.map((post) => ({
    params:
     { 
      list: `${post.store_label}`,///////////////////////////
      id: `${post.link_to}`,
  }
})) 
  return { paths, fallback:false, }
}

    } 
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  
  // const id = context.params.Id[1];
  // const url = context.params.Id[0];
//   const { params }=context;
//   console.log(params.Id[0])
  // const pagecontext.params.Id[0])
  const paramsId=context.params.id;
  const postBody = {
    store_id: paramsId,
    offer_type: "",
  };
  const offerList = await fetch('https://lencashapp.ae/api/v5/web/details',{
    method:'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(postBody),
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  })
  const store = await offerList.json(); 
  const storeDetails=store;
  // customer review
  const postComment = {
    store_id: paramsId,
    offer_type: "",
  };
  const commentApi = await fetch('https://lencashapp.ae/api/v4/web/get-comments',{
    method:'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(postComment),
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  })
  const commentResult = await commentApi.json(); 
  const comment=commentResult.comments;
 // Related Store
 const postRelated = {
  store_id: paramsId,
  offer_type: "",
};
const relatedApi = await fetch('https://lencashapp.ae/api/v5/web/related',{
  method:'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(postRelated),
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
})
const relatedResult = await relatedApi.json(); 
const related=relatedResult.stores;

  return {
    props: {
      storeDetails,
      paramsId, 
      comment,
      related,
      
    }
  };
}
export default Store;
```

How to call two API inside of getStaticPaths:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const topMenu = await fetch('https://lencashapp.ae/api/v5/web/home',{
          method:'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({ title: "React POST Request Example" }),
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    
        })
        const menus = await topMenu.json();
        const trending_path=menus.sections.trending;
const paths = trending_path.map((post) => ({
      params:
       { 
        list: `${post.store_label}`,///////////////////////////
        id: `${post.store_id}`,
    }
  })) 
    return { paths, fallback:false, }

const List= await fetch('https://lencashapp.ae/api/v5/web/list',{
          method:'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({ title: "React POST Request Example" }),
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    
        })
        const menus = await List.json();
        const ListDetails=menus.sections.List;
const paths = ListDetails.map((post) => ({
      params:
       { 
        list: `${post.store_label}`,///////////////////////////
        id: `${post.store_list_id}`,
    }
  })) 
    return { paths, fallback:false, }
}
```

Comment: _"But called mutiple API not working"_ - What's not working? Please clarify what the issue is, and try to provide a [mre].

Comment: The functional parts of your code look pretty good to me. One potential problem spot - in `getStaticPaths`, you're returning a `params.id` and you're using it for each call in `getStaticProps`. Is that right?

Comment: @juliomalves and serraosays I want to use two API call inside of getStaticPaths, how to call added above heading is "How to call two API inside of getStaticPaths:", if I use single API call inside of getStaticPaths working fine, I want to return two params.id

Comment: Do not call `return` after the first API call. Merge the 2 paths you're generating and _then_ call `return` with the result.

Comment: @juliomalves, How to merge two paths could you please provide example please

Comment: For example, assuming you rename your first `paths` to `topMenuPaths` and the second one to `listDetailsPaths`, you can merge both with `const paths = [...topMenuPaths, ...listDetailsPaths]` then return it.

Comment: @juliomalves your great working fine. thank you so much